# How to delete arguments from url

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to generate keys by clicking button and to show generated ones.
Here my view:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def get_key(request):
    if(request.GET.get('create_new_key')):
        for_whom = request.GET.get('for_whom')
        create_key(for_whom)
    created_keys = RegistrationKey.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'registration/get_key.html', {
        'created_keys':created_keys,
        })
```

And template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

{% include "core/header.html" %}

<body>
<form action="#" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="for_whom"/>
 <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Create" name="create_new_key">
</form>
<ul>
 {% for created_key in created_keys %}
  <p>{{created_key.key}}</p>
  <p>{{created_key.for_whom}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
{% include "core/footer.html" %}
</html>
```

Now when I'm clicking the button on page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_registration_key/` the key is generating but now I'm at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_registration_key/?for_whom=&create_new_key=Create#`, so refreshing this page would generate more keys.
I really need to cut this arguments from url but don't understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your view to `redirect` to the same view when a new key is created to clear the querystring, and `render` only when there is no `for_whom` argument:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def get_key(request):
    if request.GET.get('create_new_key'):
        for_whom = request.GET.get('for_whom')
        create_key(for_whom)
        return redirect('get_key')  # Use the name in your urls.py
    else:
        created_keys = RegistrationKey.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'registration/get_key.html', {
            'created_keys':created_keys,
        })
```